# WebRequest.GetRequestStream() Immediately sending Request Body

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to send xml data to a web server through a POST request. I need to send request in chunks in order to track progress.

I have realised that when I set:

```
webRequest.SendChunked = true
```

an empty request body is sent to the server when `GetRequestStream()` is called. However, when `SendChunked` is `false` and `GetRequestStream()` is called, no request is sent to the server until I am done writing to the stream and closed it or called `GetResponse`.

The following is that part of my code:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
webRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
webRequest.SendChunked = true;

// get the bytes.
byte[] xmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.reqStrTpl);
// webRequest.ContentLength = xmlBytes.Length;

Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
```

From the code as `SendChunked` is set to `true`, an empty request body is sent to the server at this call:

```
Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
```

even before I write into the stream. However, if `SendChunked = false` and I set the ContentLength, no request body is sent until I have written into the stream and called `GetResponse`.

I want to know what I am doing wrong with sending in chunks causing an empty body to be sent when GetRequestStream() is called whiles I have not even written into the stream. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you think this is wrong. It's got enough information to send the headers *now*, why should it bother using up buffer space for them when it knows that there are going to be a *number* of network round-trips anyway?

Comment: Damien can you explain further please on what I am doing wrong and the best way to write the file contents. As I indicated earlier I may be doing it wrongly that is why why I am seeking guide here.

Comment: I'm saying I don't see anything wrong here. What **issue** is being caused by it sending the headers immediately that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: So you told you want data to be sent in chunks, and it is sent in chunks. Seems all fine.

Comment: @Evk As said earlier I don't get the chance to write the request body. The server application receives empty request body. Possibly sending by chunks is not done the way I did it that is why I asked for the right way of sending data by chunks in C#.

Comment: Are you sure your server application can handle Transfer-Encoding: chunked correctly? What is that server application? Empty request body is not a problem, because you said yourself (by `SendChunked = true`) that request is delivered in multiple chunks. Server should wait for other chunks to be delivered. That is assuming you really need to use chunked transfer in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution. Just to help those who may be having similar problems:

The problem was that I was using PHP as CGI/FastCGI which is not able to handle chunked transfer properly. This is reported as a bug here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60826. I don't know if there is a fix yet.

The solution is to use PHP as apache handler. I did that and now when `WebRequest.GetRequestStream()` is called, I get the chance to write the body in chunks and it works perfectly. I captured the network packets and I could confirm that the request body was sent in chunks as I write them in the stream.

Another important thing to note is that the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` specification indicates that the data must be preceded by the data length in hexadecimal value followed by `\r\n`. For example:

```
D\r\nDaniel Oppong\r\n0\r\n\r\n
```

where D is a hexadecimal value for the data length which is 13.

When writing the data bytes do not write these yourself as it will automatically be done by the Request Object. I was initially writing them myself and realised that they are also written in data received on the server. I then thought of writing the data only and by observing the network packets, these characters were already written as part of the data before being sent. Data received on the server was complete as expected.

I hope this will help others who will be having similar problems.